# Web Components ready flag

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

We are using Web Components and Polymer on our site, and have quite a few bits of Javascript which wait for the `"WebComponentsReady"` event to be fired before executing. However, we have some asynchronous JS files which occasionally add an event listener for the event *after* it has been fired, meaning the script we want to run is never run.

Does anyone know if there is a flag for Web Components being ready which can be checked?

Something like this is what we would need:

```
if(WebComponents.ready) { // Does this flag, or something similar, exist??
    // do stuff
} else {
    document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following flag is set during bootstrap

```
window.CustomElements.ready
```

Comment: Does this cover all aspects needed for Web Components? Custom Elements is one part of 4, with HTML Imports, template tags, and shadow DOM being the others. The need is that I don't want to try to access my custom components' properties and methods until I know they are going to work.

Comment: This is the last flag to be set before dispatching the `WebComponentsReady` event. All other aspects should normally be already set up.

Comment: That's good to know, sounds like it might do the job. Cheers.